# Trouble connecting to MongoDB server using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a mongoDB server on the network. I can connect to it via RoboMongo but not through Java using their MongoDB drivers.

I did some digging and realised that in the connection settings for RoboMongo it is using a SSH tunnel to connect.

I am currently trying the current code in java, but it isn't working. Is there a way to connect through SSH for their Java driver?

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Set;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("hostname goes here");
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("songo");

        Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

        for (String s : colls) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried using a connection string and the other methods. The server is also running on the default port of 27017.

Comment: what are your connection settings for robomongo? Is it just localhost and 27017?

Comment: For robomongo it is the server hostname and the default port (27017). It's using the private key ssh settings. I can connect to my local Mongo installation fine using Java, but not the remote one.

Comment: Did you set `bind_ip` as `127.0.0.1` in `mongodb.conf`? That might be the problem. If it is so, change this line to your application server ip or remove it for full access(which is not recommended)

Comment: I'll have to check with the person in charge of the server. It's on our dev/test machine so it shouldn't be a problem to change the settings. Once we move it to production, we'll have a dedicated server.